# Opposite of :hover?

Tags: html, css, layout

I've run into a problem when creating a website. I want a different effect on mouse hover and mouse leave. By default, the element is display: none and on hover of the element it is changed to display: block. After mouse leave I want the element to stay display:block until the container's height is at 0. And CSS transitions don't support animating display. However, I need display none before hover to hide elements.

Sorry if I am explaining this poorly but it will make sense when visiting the page.

```
.overlay {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: white;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0%;
 transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 }

 .overlay h2 {
 font-family: 'Futura';
 color: black;
 font-size: 3.5rem;
 padding: 1.5rem;
 padding-bottom: 1rem;
 display: none;
 transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover .overlay {
 height: 100%;
 }

.item:hover .overlay h2 {
 display: block;
}

.item:hover .overlay p {
 display: block;
}

.overlay p {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 padding: 1.5rem;
padding-top: .5rem;
padding-bottom: 0;
display: none;
}
```

As you can see this code results in the h2 and p tags flashing out after mouse leave. What CSS could make it possible to have the h2 and p tags slide away with the .overlay element?

[Site](https://1080benchmarks.github.io/repfam2/index.html)

Comment: you need the state to be permanent, not with css though. but you may do that with js.

Comment: Try removing `display: none` from both the `h2` and the `p` tag in their default state. Add `overflow: hidden` to the overlay.

Comment: Have you tried using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: none` from your class `.overlay p` and `.overlay h2` and you do not need the `display:block` on `.item:hover .overlay h2` and `.item:hover .overlay p` as display block is the default for those.

The opposite of :hover state would be the default state, so not hovered :)

Answer (score 0):

1. add `pointer-events: none;` to `.overlay`
2. remove `display: none;` from `.overlay h2` and `.overlay p`

Comment: However, I need display: none in the default state of the element so the item caption does not appear at the bottom of the image

Comment: @Kuebiko you do not need `display: none;` to hide the item caption because your `.overlay` already has `height: 0%;` which hides it.

Comment: When I remove the display: none from the h2 and p tag at the bottom row of items the caption can be seen underneath them even though the height is at 0%. I have thought of using transition-delay and opacity but that's not the ideal look I'm going for.